# How to retrieve all friends' posts from facebook api

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to facebook api, but are there anyway to retrieve all posts from my friends (current and historical)? 
I tried

```
  me/home?limit=10000
```

but this seems to combine posts from suggested/sponsored/liked_sites which I don't want. Plus it doesn't seem to go and get all the posts

What I'm trying to do is to find when and how many times users' friends post and the likes and comments.

Answer (score 1):

With Graph API v2.0 this is no longer possible, because all the `friends_*` permissions have been removed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

With v1.0 the request would have been

```
GET /me?fields=friends.fields(posts)
```

which currently fails (at least for me) when querying all my friends data without limits. FB is applying API request limits apparently.

Using

```
GET /me?fields=friends.fields(posts.limit(10)).limit(50)
```

works, but it will only give you the last 10 posts of 50 of your friends.

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dfriends.fields(posts.limit(10)).limit(50)&version=v1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dfriends.fields%28posts.limit%2810%29%29.limit%2850%29&version=v1.0)

Comment: thanks but the url above only provides my id. is there any specific Access Token I need?

Comment: Works for me with a standard access token with `user_friends` permission.

Comment: hmmm weird, doesn't work for me, I gave user_friends permission to the access token as well

Comment: Try `friends_status` and `read_stream` as well. Have you change the Version to v1.0?

Comment: enabled both, still only giving me my id. When I click on the url above, it looks like it switches to v1.0

Comment: Well, can't help you with that. Works for me. v1.0 will anyway only work until April 30th 2015.